# Snowflake LISTAGG Encapsulate Values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, listagg

I was wondering if anyone has solved being able to encapsulate values in the `LISTAGG` function for Snowflake.

I have a table that looks something like this

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PC |
| 1 | PC,A |
| 2 | ER |

The following query:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    LISTAGG(DISTINCT NAME, ',') AS LIST
FROM TEST_TABLE
```

will return this table

| ID | LIST |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PC,PC,A |
| 2 | ER |

My expected result would be:

| ID | LIST |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PC,"PC,A" |
| 2 | ER |

Does anyone know how to get the expected result?
I thought about testing if the value had a comma and then a CASE WHEN to switch the logic based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can aggregate using a `CASE` expression which detects commas, in which case it wraps the value in double quotes.

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    LISTAGG(DISTINCT CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%,%'
                          THEN CONCAT('"', NAME, '"')
                          ELSE NAME END, ',') AS LIST
FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to use `listagg`, I would have picked a different delimiter, like so..

```
select listagg(distinct name,'|')
from t;
```

Personally, I find `array_agg` easier to work with in cases like yours

```
select array_agg(distinct name)
from t;
```

Comment: Yeah there were a couple of reasons the people downstream wanted commas and usually, I do arrays too but this needed to be varchar.